# Is there a way to save and open up a state of floatcanvas?

Tags: python, user-interface, canvas, save, wxpython

I am looking to be able to open up a saved state of floatcanvas. I was wondering if this was possible using floatcanvas for python. What type of file would I save the canvas as? Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, there does not seem to be a built in method for saving the widget's state. You might be able to use the persist portion of wxPython (http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.persist.html) and define a custom persistent window that wraps the FloatCanvas widget. Otherwise, you should ask on the wxPython Google group for assistance.